# Chrome Extension - Rename tabs based on bookmark name

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks

I'm looking for an extension/plug in that will automatically rename tabs based on my bookmark names. Working on browsers with a lot of tabs for reporting and work - wanted to just sort the tabs out.

The URL of the websites stays the same but the title regenerates (I think).

Have used Rename This and RenameTab but they don't rely on bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

The Addon - [Rename This](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rename-this/lcpjdhnnehkbbdcmdieijglnoiakofdf?hl=en-US)  supports manually renaming the title of the tabs. 
Works fine, but downside is that the renaming is not persistent and doesn't work with bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

try using
javascript:(function(){var title=prompt("New title?");document.title=title})();
or
javascript:function gcloak() { var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');link.type = 'image/x-icon';link.rel = 'shortcut icon';link.href = 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/infinite_arrow_favicon_5.ico';document.title = ' My Drive - Google  Drive';console.log(document.title);document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link) };gcloak();setInterval(gcloak, 1000);

just put it in your bookmarks (the 2nd one is better.)

I know this Is not what you want but it will at least work

Comment: Do mind formatting the code please